# A crash playing video with MPMoviePlayer

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to run this on device and get a crash on the `NSURL` definition line with no explanation :

```
   //movieplayer initialization
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"TrueDetective" ofType:@"mp4"];
    NSURL *videoURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]; //crash here
    self.moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:videoURL];
    [self.moviePlayer setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleNone];
    moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;

    [self.movieView addSubview:self.moviePlayer.view];

    [self.moviePlayer.view setFrame: self.movieView.frame];
    [self.moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
    [self.moviePlayer play];
```

The exact file is in my project folder .
What am i missing here ?

Comment: did you check if path is null by any chance ? did you try do debug it ? there must be some exception for the crash

Comment: ok i log the path and it says null…. the movie is in there, and i even tried to remove him and recopy..

Comment: did you add it to your project via Xcode?

Comment: i can even play it within xcode