# Movie player failed to play

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to play video with this guide :http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Video_Playback_from_within_an_iOS_7_Application

so i have :

```
//movieplayer initialization
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:
              @"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CS-6gJkNAo4"];

self.moviePlayer =  [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]
                 initWithContentURL:url];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:)
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                           object:self.moviePlayer];

self.moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleDefault;
self.moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = YES;
[self.movieView addSubview:self.moviePlayer.view];
 [self.moviePlayer setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];
```

Where the player is loaded to some view .
I don't see nothing and i only get this error message :

```
_itemFailedToPlayToEnd: {
    kind = 1;
    new = 2;
    old = 0;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [A crash playing video with MPMoviePlayer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22449361/a-crash-playing-video-with-mpmovieplayer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MPMoviePlayerController can't play Youtube video. You have to paste direct link to file to play video in such way.